# Visualization api - hide data from displaying on browser using servlet

Tags: servlets

Generally the servlet extends httpservlet but in the code below
the servlet extends DataSourceServlet
and the page is created like this
The text begins with google.visualization.Query.setResponse
and ends with {c:[{v:'Bob'},{v:'Jane'}]}]}});  **on the browser**

code:   http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/dev/dsl_csv.html
can  you please guide me as to how can i make servlet page silent
without giving the output on the browser.?  so that i can directly call the javascript page for drawing the chart

I want to integrate all the code but i am not able to remove this browser from coming.
I am new to servlet please help

Answer (score 0):

Ok I will explain my doubt again
I am writting this servlet code 
http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/dev/dsl_csv.html#intro
the url to execute is /CsvDataSourceServlet?url=http://localhost:8084/WebApplication1/**F2.csv**
When i execute this code i get output result on my browser ... I am not understanding how that code is opening my browser and showing
{c:[{v:'Bob'},{v:'Jane'}]}]}});  etc etc
why is this happening , why is the browser opening to show result
can we figure out something from this code
**http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/dev/dsl_csv.html#intro**

were F2.csv is my *.csv file

now after executing the code I have to display the result which i have to do using the javascript code as follows



  All Examples

// Load the Visualization API and the ready-made Google table visualization.
  google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['annotatedtimeline']});

// Set a callback to run when the API is loaded.
  google.setOnLoadCallback(init);

// Send the queries to the data sources.
  function init() {

```
//var query = new google.visualization.Query('simpleexample?tq=select name,population');
//query.send(handleSimpleDsResponse);
```

var  query = new google.visualization.Query('CsvDataSourceServlet?url=http://localhost:8084/WebApplication1/**F2.csv**');
    query.send(handleCsvDsResponse);

}

// Handle the csv data source query response
  function handleCsvDsResponse(response) {
    if (response.isError()) {
      alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
      return;
    }
   var data = response.getDataTable();
  var chart = new google.visualization.AnnotatedTimeLine(document.getElementById('csv_div'));
   chart.draw(data, {displayAnnotations: true});
  }

## CSV Data Source

An organization chart.
  The data is taken from the csv data source.